# Can't read file after split line?

Tags: file, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

```
file = open("songs.txt" , "r")
songs = {}

for line in file:
    (song, name) = line.split(",")
    songs[song] = str(name)

print(songs)

songs = {}

print("Welcome to the Virtual Playlist!")

while True:
    print("")
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("1. View the playlist")
    print("2. View playlist sorted by artist name")
    print("3. View playlist sorted by song name")
    print("5. Add a song")
    print("6. Exit")
    choice = input("").strip()

    if choice == "1":
        print(file.read())
```

I am trying to read from a file then output everything in it, it works fine if I exclude the part where it reads every line and stores it into a dictionary. But it doesn't work if that part is included. Why is this happening?

Also, when it stores the songs and artists into a dictionary, it includes /n in some of the entries since there a space there in the file. Is there any way to exclude that /n thing because I just wan't the song name/artist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at the end of file after this loop `for line in file:`. Therefore, the next `file.read()` has nothing to read. If you really want to read the file again, you can go to the beginning with:

```
file.seek(0)
```

But you already have read all the songs in `songs` why redefine `songs = {}` and deleting them again? Why not:

```
if choice == "1":   
    for song, name in songs.items():
        print(name, song)
```

Use `strip()` to get rid of the `\n` characters:

```
song, name = line.strip().split(",")
```